# How can I Center an image within a fixed specified crop frame with graphicsmagick C library

Tags: c, thumbnails, photos, graphicsmagick

Hey, I was wondering if someone knows a good way to scale an image while maintaining aspect ratio, and then center it with respect to a specified fixed crop area.

The first part is straight forward (resizing while maintaining ratio), just need help with the second part.

Here is a link to something that does this with php and image gd.. [PHP crop image to fix width and height without losing dimension ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255773/php-crop-image-to-fix-width-and-height-without-losing-dimension-ratio)

Another link to what I want to achieve is the "Crop" strategy on this page:
http://transloadit.com/docs/image-resize#resize-strategies

I want to do this using the graphicsmagick C library.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please do share the solution.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just post the solution if you've figured it out?...