# Crop the image with aspect ratio 5:3 using php

Tags: php, crop

I have image saved on my server and I want to crop this image with aspect ratio 5:3 using php (no extra library required). I have to generate different thumbnails of size 1024px, 960px, 500, 350px, 120px.

I am not getting how to calculate aspect ratio so thumbnails generated are of correct 5:3

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3256004/1438393) not answer your question?

Comment: This question is creating the images using aspect ratio 1:1 but I need to create thumbnails using aspect ratio 5:3

Comment: I have found the answer from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855996/crop-image-in-php/1856049#1856049