# php how to crop image then stretch to prevent black bar

Tags: php

i looking for solution of crop images to square but the result have issue with black bar on both side if the image's ratio to0 big.

```
eg:
croped
http://static.xaluan.com/images/news/Image/2013/11/13/med_15282b4691c7e6.img.jpg
original
http://static.xaluan.com/images/news/Image/2013/11/1315282b4691c7e6.img.jpg
```

I have tried with solution of filling that blackbar with other color but result not really nice.

So i thinking of after crop the images need to be stretching a bit in thumble so people not notice of changing of images in thumbles but the blackbar will go away will be nice.
Please help to work this out
thanks
following my code:

```
            $src_width= ImagesX($src_img);
            $src_height= ImagesY($src_img);
            $dest_width = $insize;
            $dest_height = $src_height/($src_width/$dest_width);
            if ( $cropYes == 1){
                       if($src_width > $src_height) $biggestSide = $src_width; //find biggest length
                       else $biggestSide = $src_height; 
                       $cropPercent = .7; // This will zoom in to 70% zoom (crop)
                       $cropWidth   = $biggestSide*$cropPercent; 
                       $cropHeight  = $biggestSide*$cropPercent; 
                       $xcrop = ($src_width-$cropWidth)/2;
                       if ($src_width >= $src_height){
                       $ycrop = ($src_height-$cropHeight)/2;  //use this if need from center
                       } else {$ycrop = 0; }//set crop from top images
            $dest_img = ImageCreateTrueColor($dest_width, $dest_width);
            ImageCopyResampled($dest_img, $src_img, 0, 0, $xcrop, $ycrop, $dest_width, $dest_width, $cropWidth, $cropHeight); 
//          $white = imagecolorallocate($dest_img, 255, 255, 255);
//          imagefill($dest_img, 0, 0, $white); // set backgound to white
```

Comment: the `example original image` has been removed now~~, can you update another available example image??

Answer (score 1):

Try this code by Sven Koschnicke:

```
//Your Image
$imgSrc = "image.jpg";

//getting the image dimensions
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imgSrc);

//saving the image into memory (for manipulation with GD Library)
$myImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgSrc);

// calculating the part of the image to use for thumbnail
if ($width > $height) {
  $y = 0;
  $x = ($width - $height) / 2;
  $smallestSide = $height;
} else {
  $x = 0;
  $y = ($height - $width) / 2;
  $smallestSide = $width;
}

// copying the part into thumbnail
$thumbSize = 100;
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbSize, $thumbSize);
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $myImage, 0, 0, $x, $y, $thumbSize, $thumbSize, $smallestSide, $smallestSide);

//final output
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($thumb);
```

Source: [PHP crop image to fix width and height without losing dimension ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255773/php-crop-image-to-fix-width-and-height-without-losing-dimension-ratio)

Answer (score 1):

I have written a class for manipulating images, save this as a php file and include in your code:

```
Class Resize {

//Variables
private $image;
private $width;
private $height;
private $imageResized;
private $imageAplha;

function __construct($fileName, $tmpFile = NULL) {
    //Open Image
    $this->image = $this->openImage($fileName, $tmpFile);

    //Get width and height
    $this->width = imagesx($this->image);
    $this->height = imagesy($this->image);
}

private function openImage($file, $tmpFile = NULL) {
    //Get extension
    $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    if ($tmpFile != NULL) {
        $cfile = $tmpFile;
    } else {
        $cfile = $file;
    }

    switch ($extension) {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg':
            $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($cfile);
            $this->imageAplha = false;
            break;
        case 'gif':
            $img = @imagecreatefromgif($cfile);
            $this->imageAplha = false;
            break;
        case 'png':
            $img = @imagecreatefrompng($cfile);
            imagealphablending($img, true);
            $this->imageAplha = true;
            break;
        default:
            $img = false;
            break;
    }
    return $img;
}

public function resizeImage($newWidth, $newHeight, $option = "auto") {
    //Get optimal width and height ( based on option )
    $optionArray = $this->getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option);

    $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
    $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];


    //Resample - Create image canvas of w, h size
    $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight);

    if ($this->imageAplha) {

        imagealphablending($this->imageResized, false);
        imagesavealpha($this->imageResized, true);
    }

    imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $this->width, $this->height);


    //If CROP
    if ($option == 'crop') {
        $this->crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight);
    }
}

private function getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option) {

    switch ($option) {
        case 'exact':
            $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
            $optimalHeight = $newHeight;
            break;
        case 'portrait':
            $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
            $optimalHeight = $newHeight;
            break;
        case 'landscape':
            $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
            $optimalHeight = $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
            break;
        case 'auto':
            $optionArray = $this->getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight);
            $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
            $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
            break;
        case 'crop':
            $optionArray = $this->getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight);
            $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
            $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
            break;
    }
    return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
}

private function getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight) {
    $ratio = $this->width / $this->height;
    $newWidth = $newHeight * $ratio;
    return $newWidth;
}

private function getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth) {
    $ratio = $this->height / $this->width;
    $newHeight = $newWidth * $ratio;
    return $newHeight;
}

private function getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight) {
    if ($this->height < $this->width) {
    //Image to be resized is wider (landscape)
        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
        $optimalHeight = $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
    } elseif ($this->height > $this->width) {
    //Image to be resized is taller (portrait)
        $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
        $optimalHeight = $newHeight;
    } else {
    //Image to be resizerd is a square
        if ($newHeight < $newWidth) {
            $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
            $optimalHeight = $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
        } else if ($newHeight > $newWidth) {
            $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
            $optimalHeight = $newHeight;
        } else {
            //Sqaure being resized to a square
            $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
            $optimalHeight = $newHeight;
        }
    }

    return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
}

private function getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight) {

    $heightRatio = $this->height / $newHeight;
    $widthRatio = $this->width / $newWidth;

    if ($heightRatio < $widthRatio) {
        $optimalRatio = $heightRatio;
    } else {
        $optimalRatio = $widthRatio;
    }

    $optimalHeight = $this->height / $optimalRatio;
    $optimalWidth = $this->width / $optimalRatio;

    return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
}

private function crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight) {
    //Find center - this will be used for the crop
    $cropStartX = ( $optimalWidth / 2) - ( $newWidth / 2 );
    $cropStartY = ( $optimalHeight / 2) - ( $newHeight / 2 );

    $crop = $this->imageResized;

    //Now crop from center to exact requested size
    $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);

    if ($this->imageAplha) {

        imagealphablending($this->imageResized, false);
        imagesavealpha($this->imageResized, true);
    }

    imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $crop, 0, 0, $cropStartX, $cropStartY, $newWidth, $newHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight);
}

public function saveImage($savePath, $imageQuality = "100") {
    //Get extension
    $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($savePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    switch ($extension) {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg':
            if (imagetypes() & IMG_JPG) {
                imagejpeg($this->imageResized, $savePath, $imageQuality);
            }
            break;

        case 'gif':
            if (imagetypes() & IMG_GIF) {
                imagegif($this->imageResized, $savePath);
            }
            break;

        case 'png':
            //Scale quality from 0-100 to 0-9
            $scaleQuality = round(($imageQuality / 100) * 9);

            //Invert quality setting as 0 is best, not 9
            $invertScaleQuality = 9 - $scaleQuality;

            if (imagetypes() & IMG_PNG) {
                imagepng($this->imageResized, $savePath, $invertScaleQuality);
            }
            break;

        default:
            //No extension - No save.
            break;
    }

    imagedestroy($this->imageResized);
}

}
```

You can then call and resize/crop the image using:

```
$resizeObj = new resize([filetomanipulate]);
$resizeObj->resizeImage([width], [height], [exact, portrait, landscape, auto, crop]);
$resizeObj->saveImage([outputfilename], [quality{0-100}]);
```

Hope you find this helpful.. Happy coding :)